# Upload with AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, upload

I'm trying to upload a file with AJAX.
if i do a vardump:

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

I get an array filled with information.
But if i do this:

```
$try = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

$try is false who can help me?

javascript:

```
    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php?command=upload',  //Server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){ // Check if upload property exists
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // For handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        //Ajax events
       // beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
        //success: completeHandler,
        //error: errorHandler,
        // Form data
        data: formData,
        //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});

function progressHandlingFunction(e){
    if(e.lengthComputable){
        $('progress').attr({value:e.loaded,max:e.total});
    }
}
```

the var_dump from $_FILES

```
array(1) {
  ["file"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "1.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpATNNIs"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(220559)
  }
}
```

thanks

Comment: and the javascript code where is it ?

Comment: look here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/

Comment: Could you please give us the entire output of $_FILES ?

Comment: Check once if upload folder has write permission.

Comment: Have you verified that PHP has got WRITE permissions on the upload folder? I also note that you are using an relative path 'upload/' maybe you should make it absolute?

Comment: It is local so everything had white permission, and makeing it absolute has nog difference.

Comment: Try using a try/catch statement:
`try {
    $try = move_uploaded_file(...);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing your own code, please use this good script for uploading files using ajax.
https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader

hope this will work for you, its very simple to use and you can easily modify it.